# Autohotkey - How to navigate a radio list using up and down arrow keys?

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following script. I'm not sure how I can modify it to navigate the results using the up or down arrow keys. To run it, just create a .txt file and add some words in there (one word per line), then edit the filepath to where your .txt file is located. Then just search for a keyword that is found in at least 2 of the lines. e.g

```
Word1
Word2
```

If you search for word, it will return both word1 and word2. Then I just need to choose between them using up and down arrow key.

```
F9::
{
    FilePath := "D:\5. Programs\AutoHotkey L x64\test.txt"
    Gui, Destroy
    Gui, Font, S20
    Gui, Add, Text, X25 Y10 W450 H30 +Center , Search Box
    Gui, Font, S10
    Gui, Add, Edit, XP Y+20 W450 H20 vSearchString, 
    Gui, Color
    Gui, Show, W500 H100, Search Box
    return

    #IfWinActive, Search Box
    {
    Enter::
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
        ResultList := []
        ChosenString := ""
        Loop, Read, %FilePath%
        {
            if (InStr(A_LoopReadLine, SearchString))
            {
                ResultList.Push(A_LoopReadLine)
            }
        }
        if (!ResultList.Length())
        {
            ;MsgBox % "No match found!"
            return
        }
        Gui, DisplayResults:New,-MaximizeBox -MinimizeBox  , Search results
        Gui, Add, Text, w250, % "Click on one of the results below:"
        for key, value in ResultList
        {
            if (key = 1)
                Gui, Add, Radio, gSelectResult vChosenString, %value%
            else
                Gui, Add, Radio, gSelectResult, %value%
        }
        Gui, DisplayResults:Show
        return
        
    SelectResult:
        Gui, DisplayResults:Submit
        ;Msgbox, % ResultList[ChosenString]
        Clipboard := % ResultList[ChosenString]
        return
    }
}
return
```

Comment: You're confirming the selection as soon as the user selects one of the radio buttons. (Moving with the arrows keys selects the one you move on top of, just like clicking would) So you're looking to add some other way of confirming the selection? Maybe add a "Confirm" button, or maybe make hitting Enter confirm?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the GUI to disappear?
Add `NoHide` in line number 44 like this:

`Gui, DisplayResults:Submit, NoHide`.